# Identification on a Sci-fi paperback about a girl on a floating city

Tags: story-identification

A while back, I read a book written in the late 80s, early 90s, I think, but I can only vaguely remember anything about it, so here goes.

1. The copy I read was English, but it may have been translated
2. It takes place on a floating city on a planet that is either all water or mostly water
3. The protagonist is a young girl with a name that sounded vaguely Russian when I read it, but I might be wrong
4. The girl's parents won't allow her off the city up into space to go to some university, like her other brothers and sisters were, and one day she somehow finds out she's had parts of her replaced with android parts.
5. I think she has to find out what happened to her to make her part robot and why her parents are so protective of her and then take revenge on the person who had attacked her, but I didn't finish the book and I don't know how it ended.

I would really like to find this book again, and have looked for it, but all effort I made was fruitless, and I still don't have a clue what it could possibly be.

Comment: If you've searched for this already, did you find any books with a similar premise that weren't the right one? If so, you should edit your answer to name any such books, so that no one bothers to submit them as answers.

Comment: Floating as in floating on water or in the air?

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen I believe it was water, but I don't know for certain.